# Custom Implementation of Asp.NET identity with existing WCF Services backend for user management

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

At my workplace, we have many existing applications for which common WCF services have been written to expose user and role management functionality at the enterprise level. So, for example, to create a new user, our applications just call the Create method exposed by our UserService.

We are trying to build a new MVC5 web application which needs identity management features. I have found several examples of custom implementation of the ASP.NET identity framework which typically override the `IUser`, `IUserManager`, etc. I also found an implementation for MySQL database instead of SQL server. *However, I am unable to figure out if it is possible to completely discard away the database part of the framework and hand over the persistence calls to our services but still use methods and facade provided by the framework for cookie management, Owin integration etc*. Or enterprise schema, of course, does not match the default Identity framework database schema.

I looked at the Identity Sample from Microsoft that implements a user manager:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

This custom user manager `ApplicationUserManager` needs a `UserStore<ApplicationUser>`, which needs a `ApplicationDbContext`. Is it possible to pass some service instance instead to the custom UserStore instead of a DbContext. *Can the UserStore even work without a dependency on some database DbContext?*